# How do I go about turning prexisting code that requires specific type parameters to generic type parameters for this example?

Tags: c#, graph

I'm building a graph with objects as vertices instead of integers as vertices as per this example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bridge-in-a-graph/

The piece of code I want to ask about is the below:

```
void bridgeUtil(int u, boolean visited[], int disc[],
                int low[], int parent[])
{

    // Count of children in DFS Tree
    int children = 0;

    // Mark the current node as visited
    visited[u] = true;

    // Initialize discovery time and low value
    disc[u] = low[u] = ++time;

    // Go through all vertices aadjacent to this
    Iterator<Integer> i = adj[u].iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        int v = i.next();  // v is current adjacent of u

        // If v is not visited yet, then make it a child
        // of u in DFS tree and recur for it.
        // If v is not visited yet, then recur for it
        if (!visited[v])
        {
            parent[v] = u;
            bridgeUtil(v, visited, disc, low, parent);

            // Check if the subtree rooted with v has a
            // connection to one of the ancestors of u
            low[u]  = Math.min(low[u], low[v]);

            // If the lowest vertex reachable from subtree
            // under v is below u in DFS tree, then u-v is
            // a bridge
            if (low[v] > disc[u])
                System.out.println(u+" "+v);
        }

        // Update low value of u for parent function calls.
        else if (v != parent[u])
            low[u]  = Math.min(low[u], disc[v]);
    }
}
```

It has a bunch of arrays where an element is selected by using the vertices (which are integers) as index in the array.

How do I turn this bridgeUtil method into a method that can accept generic types as the vertices instead of integers?

Would I use Dictionaries instead like so?

```
void BridgeUtil(K u, Dictionary<K, bool> visited, Dictionary<K, int> disc, Dictionary<K, int> low, Dictionary<K, K> parent)
{
    int children = 0;
    int time = 0;

    visited[u] = true;

    disc[u] = low[u] = time++;

    List<K> neighbors = GetAllNeighbors(u);

    foreach (var v in neighbors)
    {
        if (!visited[v])
        {
            parent[v] = u;
            BridgeUtil(v, visited, disc, low, parent);

            low[u] = Math.Min(low[u], low[v]);

            if (low[v] > disc[u])
            {
                Debug.Log(u + " <> " + v);
            }

        }

        else if (!v.Equals(parent[u]))
        {
            low[u] = Math.Min(low[u], disc[v]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I substitute `Iterator<Integer> i = adj[u].iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())` with a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to add the K as part of the signature:

```
void BridgeUtil<K>(K u, Dictionary<K, bool> visited, Dictionary<K, int> disc, Dictionary<K, int> low, Dictionary<K, K> parent)
```

Besides that, GetAllNeighbors(u); cant get only u, it mush gets visited, disc, low and parent.

Comment: Could you explain your last line in more detail? `GetAllNeighbors(u)` simply returns a list of all adjacent vertices. The original code used a special java iterator `adj[u].iterator()` but C# doesn't have this so I replaced it with a for loop. Does this not work?

Comment: GetAllNeighbors(u) is something you need to write - C#  does not have this function, so, I'm guessing it will get all the Neighbors of u, in order to do so,  you need the other arrays: visited, disc, low and parent - right?